# How do I export Firestore data to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to export Firestore data to Google Cloud Storage automatically on a regular schedule (so that I can then import it into BigQuery for analysis).

[Schedule data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) does outline a way to export data from Firestore on a schedule, but it is JavaScript for running on Node.js: I want to avoid that & would **prefer to stick to an all-Java solution** on the server side.

[Export and import data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) offers another way — using the `gcloud` command-line utility — to export Firestore data to GCS. However, I don't want to schedule the script to run on my laptop & then have to ensure that my laptop is switched on at the right time **and** has an active Internet connection. I am looking for an entirely App Engine (Standard)-based solution that can be run as a `cron` job.

At the time of writing there doesn't seem to be a programmatic way to do this using the Firebase Admin SDK (version 6.6.0) for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in utilizing the [Firestore REST API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/) directly.

In the code below I have used the Google's [HTTP Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/) (which should be your default choice on App Engine (Standard) anyway) for making the necessary network calls.

```
public static final String DEF_GCS_BUCKET_NAME = PROJECT_ID + ".appspot.com";

public static final String FIRESTORE_API_V1BETA2 =
        "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta2";

public static final String FIRESTORE_DB = "/projects/" + PROJECT_ID
        + "/databases/(default)";

public static final String FIRESTORE_EXPORT_GCS_LOC = "gs://"
        + DEF_GCS_BUCKET_NAME + "/firestore-export/";

public static final String FIRESTORE_EXPORT_GCS_ROOT = "firestore-export/";

private static final String FUNC_EXPORT_DOCUMENTS = ":exportDocuments";

@javax.annotation.CheckForNull
public static Operation exportCollectionToGcs(@lombok.NonNull String collection)
        throws IOException {

    AccessToken token = tokenFor(serviceAc());
    Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
    payload.put("collectionIds", Arrays.asList(collection));
    payload.put("outputUriPrefix", FIRESTORE_EXPORT_GCS_LOC + collection);

    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(FIRESTORE_API_V1BETA2 + FIRESTORE_DATABASE
        + FUNC_EXPORT_DOCUMENTS);
    HttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(jacksonFactory(), payload);
    HttpRequest req = requestFactory().buildPostRequest(url, content);
    req.getHeaders().setAuthorization("Bearer " + token.getTokenValue())
    Operation op = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse res = req.execute();
        // Parse the response JSON to populate an Operation POJO
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        // Handle the error
    }
    return op;
}
```

This starts a Firestore [Operation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Operation) to export the specified collection to GCS. You can then [*get* the status of the Operation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.operations/get) if you want to do something when it finishes (or just to send/prepare a report).

Ensure that the service account you use has the requisite permissions (described in [Schedule data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export)).

Comment: This is a nice example. Can you post the entire code to make this a real world example? For example your code for authorization (service account) is not present. I will vote for a complete example.

Comment: That's separate from the issue at hand. Maybe I'll add that as a different Q&A ;-).